# Only accept non-negative numbers Java

Tags: java

```
else if (bb.equals("Dollar") && cc.equals("Pound")){
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What amount would you like to convert?:");
        double aa = Double.parseDouble(input);
        double output =(aa*rate);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.format("Your amount is: $%.2f",  output));
```

---

How do I make this so that if someone enters a negative number a message will popup saying invalid input?

Comment: `if (number < 0) {show message}`

Comment: When I use an if statement like if (input < 0) the program won't accept it. Could someone explain?

Comment: What do you mean by "program won't accept it"?

Comment: I am using eclipse, and there are the red squiggly lines.

Comment: `input` is a string, `0` is an integer, you can't use the `<` operator to compare the two.

Comment: So how do you recommend me changing it? I am really new to programming and am trying to get the concept. Thanks for the information.

Comment: Well `aa` is a double, so you can compare that with 0.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the number you're checking to see if it's positive is defined by the variable `aa`? Personally I prefer using `BigDecimal` when it comes to dealing with monetary values, in which case I would do:

```
BigDecimal aa = null;
try {
    aa = new BigDecimal(input);
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    //Not a numerical value, throw an error
}
if (aa.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) <= 0) {
    //Value is negative
}
```

Comment: It says to use BigDecimal I have to import java.math. Thing is, I'm not allowed to

Comment: @jkjk why not? You're allowed importing classes from the swing package when you use `JOptionPane`.

Comment: I mean my teacher does not allow me to. I do not know why and there is no arguing with him.

Comment: Sounds like you need a new teacher, but anyway, the `Double` class also has a `compareTo` method so you can compare your value with 0, much in the same way I'm doing it with my `BigDecimal` example.